# Outlook web addIn dropdown menu

Tags: web, outlook-addin, office-js

I have created the Outlook Web Add-in project and trying th create the dropdown menu by following the link under

```
https://github.com/officedev/outlook-add-in-command-demo
```

It seems that dropdown menu just take static list. What i want to do is i have webservices which is returning some destination and link of that destionation . I want to display the list of all those destination under the dropdown and by clicking one of it, it opens the link into task pane. 
Any tips ? how to display from webservice in dropdown menu.

Comment: I don't think it's possible . You set the names of the drop-down menu items in the manifest file... and I don't think it's possible dynamically

Comment: hmmm ok then can i display all the targets in task pane  from webservice ? and when click on that it open the new popup or new task pane ?

Comment: or just suggest what wud be best option .i have to change all design then . maybe just static one item and by clicking on that i shud display all targets in popup aur in task pane ?

Comment: You want to set one static item and then after click to show all of options ? I also think that it's not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to dynamically populate the dropdowns, your best bet would be to have a single taskpane action, then render a selector page that dynamically shows the available options, then navigate to the page associated with that option. Feel free to upvote [this User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13225365-support-dynamic-content-in-add-in-commands-ribbon) suggestion to let us know that this feature is important to you.